# Models from Redis-OM are not recognized as BaseModel in Pydantic

Tags: redis, fastapi, pydantic, redis-py, redis-om

I am trying to use redis_om for my FastAPI cache but I get errors.

fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'app.models.redis_models.Customer'> is a valid Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None. Read more: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/

It says Customer is not a Pydantic model, but it should be.

`Customer` class I defined is a `HashModel` of aredis_om,
`HashModel` is a `RedisModel` of aredis_om,
and `RedisModel` is `BaseModel` of Pydantic.

`class Customer(HashModel):`

`class HashModel(RedisModel, abc.ABC):`

`class RedisModel(BaseModel, abc.ABC, metaclass=ModelMeta):`

But when I check if `Customer` is a subclass of `BaseModel`,
it says it is not a subclass.

And it also said Hashmodel and RedisModel is not a BaseModel.
Why does this happen and how to fix this problem?

code

```py
from pydantic import EmailStr
import datetime
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel
from aredis_om import HashModel, get_redis_connection, Migrator

from app.common.config import settings


redis_conn = get_redis_connection(url=settings.REDIS_DATA_URL, decode_responses=True)


class Customer(HashModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: EmailStr
    join_date: datetime.date
    age: int
    bio: Optional[str]

    class Meta:
        database = redis_conn


Migrator().run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if issubclass(Customer, BaseModel):
        print("Customer class is a subclass of BaseModel.")
    else:
        print("Customer class is NOT a subclass of BaseModel.")
```

result

```bash
Customer class is NOT a subclass of BaseModel.
```

```ini
pydantic-settings = "^2.0.3"
redis-om = "^0.2.1"
fastapi-cache2 = {extras = ["redis"], version = "^0.2.1"}
pydantic = "^2.0"
```

These are my dependencies.

Comment: `aredis_om` uses the v1 BaseModel type from pydantic v2, not the direct v2 `BaseModel`: https://github.com/redis/redis-om-python/blob/main/aredis_om/_compat.py#L7 - so you're not checking for the correct class. Check against `BaseModel` from `pydantic.v1` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aredis_om uses the BaseModel class from version 1 of Pydantic. This is provided as a separate class  type from pydantic v2, and [is what is being used aredis_om](https://github.com/redis/redis-om-python/blob/main/aredis_om/_compat.py#L7) - so you're not checking for the correct class.

Check against BaseModel from the `pydantic.v1` module instead (as shown in the linked compatibility layer:

```py
from pydantic.version import VERSION as PYDANTIC_VERSION


PYDANTIC_V2 = PYDANTIC_VERSION.startswith("2.")

if PYDANTIC_V2:
    from pydantic.v1 import BaseModel, validator
...
```